# How to search multiple file names in Nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, search

How to search for multiple file names at once in Ubuntu via the GUI? I tried Nautilus but without success.

Comment: I don't know if you will find a easy way to do this in Nautilus, but in terminal you can use this example: `find . -type f \( -name "*.class" -o -name "*.sh" \)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gnome-search-tool`

It's available in the software centre, or via `sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool`.

When you run it, rather than enter things to the 'Name contains' box, click on 'Select more options', then the drop down and choose 'Name matches regular expression', then click add.  In the new box that appears, you can use any regular expression to search file names.  If you want file1 or file2, then type `file1|file2`.

This is someone else's image, but it illustrates the method:

[image]

There are a number of options for searching, and regular expressions (regex) are very powerful, googling may find you further examples to try.

The program does not index your files, so if you search a large area, it may take a while.

Integrating with Nautilus:

A Nautilus-script will allow you to launch `gnome-search-tool` within the current directory.  Simple create a file called `Search Here` in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`, and put:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gnome-search-tool --path=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
```

as the entire file contents.  Then, set the file as executable (under Properties, Permissions).  Now, close all instances of Nautilus, and reopen one.  When you right-click in a directory, there should be a submenu called 'Scripts', under which 'Search Here' appears.  This will open `gnome-search-tool` in the current directory.

Comment: That was the problem, no regular expressions applicable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Do you mean that my answer doesn't solve your problem because there is no applicable regular expression, or that Nautilus doesn't accept regular expressions?

Nautilus does not understand regular expressions, so if you want a GUI search which does, then I have given an example.  If you want to integrate it with Nautilus a bit more, then a script could to so: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Can we search for multiple file names in `gnome-search-tool`? I have a file that contains names of all files that have to be moved some where else, now there are no regular expression to indicated them. If i will put *.htm it will obviously index all htm files, i want to put all the file names which are different[i.e. cabug.htm grahew.htm killbil.htm so on, nothing regular about them], to search all of them at once or feed the file containing all file names to an command line search utility to index them in one place or `mv` them to specified folder.

Comment: `If you want file1 or file2, then type file1|file2` this method is not working in my system.

Comment: Interesting, it works perfectly for me.  You are definitely typing that into the new box that appears, not the one at the top of the program?

Comment: I got it Frankie but it's just not working in my end:( ![A snapshot](http://i1082.photobucket.com/albums/j375/drofart/Screenshotfrom2013-05-30165255.png)

Comment: ![See this too](http://i1082.photobucket.com/albums/j375/drofart/Screenshotfrom2013-05-30171100.png)

Comment: May it be a bug on my side ?

Comment: You need to select 'Name matches regular expression' from the dropdown _before_ you click the 'add' button next to it.  Then it will create a box which understands regular expressions.  In you second screenshot you are typing in a box labelled 'Contains the text'.